# Can we have Shared Checkpoint in QTP

Tags: qtp

As we do with Object repository. We can export the check point, merge or re-use check points in other QTP scripts.

I tried with the OR Manager and did not find any option.

Kindly let me know if this can be done. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Local Object Repository is exported all Checkpoint and Output objects are exported (as well as regular Test Objects).

Then once the Shared Object Repository is associated with an action the checkpoints are available for use in that action.